Terminal+Gorenstein 3-fold over non-closed fields satisfies ($\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier implies Cartier)
Let X be a 3 dimensional normal, terminal and Gorenstein variety over non-closed field k of characteristic 0. There is a known result from the 80's by Kawamata stating that with this hypothesis any $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier divisor is in fact Cartier when $k=\mathbb{C}$. By the Lefschetz Principle this should extend to other algebraically closed fields with the same characteristic.
Is this result known over non-closed fields? Is there a known counterexample? The proof relies on topological methods so I am not sure how one could extend it.

why not take base change to an algebraically closed field?

Because factoriality (or even Q-factoriality) is not in general preserved under field extension. So if I have some Q-Cartier divisor I want to conclude is Cartier going to the field extension a priori will not help.

ok, now I understood your point
